# C prorgramming, send wav file over udp

Tags: c, sockets, udp, client-server

I created a UDP client/server communication in order to test sending wav files, the client send each time a buffer of 2048 samples of the file to the server. The problem is, for each buffer, only the first half (1024 samples) of the buffer is sent correctly, I couldn't figure out the reason behind this error.

Here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFLEN1 512
#define BUFLEN2 2048
#define PORT 8888
void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other);
    char fileaddress[BUFLEN1];
    short buf[BUFLEN2];
    FILE *file;
    int k;

    if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (inet_aton(SERVER , &si_other.sin_addr) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter file address: ");
    gets(fileaddress);
    file=fopen(fileaddress,"rb");
    while ((k = fread(buf, sizeof(short), BUFLEN2, file)) > 0) {
        if (sendto(s, buf, BUFLEN2 , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)==-1)
        {
            die("sendto()");
        }
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFLEN2 2048
#define PORT 8888

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}
int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

    int s, i, slen = sizeof(si_other) , recv_len;
    short buf[BUFLEN2];

    //create a UDP socket
    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //bind socket to port
    if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
        die("bind");
    }
    printf("Waiting for data...\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    while(1)
    {
        recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN2, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
        if (recv_len == -1)
        {
            die("recvfrom()");
        }
    }
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not answering to the question but if you're transfering files, you're most likely wrong using UDP. You should consider using TCP which is safer regarding data corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are reading in (possibly as many as) `(BUFLEN2*sizeof(short))` bytes into your buffer:

```
while ((k = fread(buf, sizeof(short), BUFLEN2, file)) > 0) {
```

... and here you are sending `BUFLEN2` bytes to the UDP socket:

```
 if (sendto(s, buf, BUFLEN2, 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)==-1)
```

... and here you are receiving (possibly as many as) `BUFLEN2` bytes from the UDP socket:

```
recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN2, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
```

I think what you need to do is replace `BUFLEN2` with `k*sizeof(short)` in your `sendto()` call, and replace `BUFLEN2` with `sizeof(buf)` in your `recvfrom()` call, so that you will send and receive all of the data and not just the first half of it.

Answer (score 0):

Its most probably either because of the window size(amount of data that can be sent in a packet) or the light-weight IP stack size(I believe this is more probable) which is related to the total maximum amount of bytes you can send at one function call.

If the problem is the window size, you can divide your data and re-assemble in the client as it arrives.
If it is stack size you can simply look for where it is defined and change it

I see your libraries doesn't contain lwip, but whatever you are using it must have something conceptually similar.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Window size is a TCP thing... you might be thinking of MTU.